# C# datagridview column sort mode automatic throw error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I made several form that have datagridview. When I clicked header for sorting some form throw me 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index' and other work. All form get data from database.

Data binding:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = conn.selectData("select * from customer").Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.Columns["id"].DataPropertyName = "idCust";
            dataGridView1.Columns["namadg"].DataPropertyName = "namaCust";
            dataGridView1.Columns["alamatdg"].DataPropertyName = "alamatCust";
            dataGridView1.Columns["telpdg"].DataPropertyName = "telpCust";
            dataGridView1.Columns["emaildg"].DataPropertyName = "emailCust";
            dataGridView1.Columns["keterangandg"].DataPropertyName = "keterangan";
            dataGridView1.Columns["memberdg"].DataPropertyName = "member";
            dataGridView1.Columns["tglmemberdg"].DataPropertyName = "tglMember";
            dataGridView1.Columns["noMemberdg"].DataPropertyName = "noMember";
```

Comment: are you binding with `List` directly? try binding with `BindingList` instead.

Comment: no, I get the data from dataset

Comment: what **type** is the `DataSource`?